# Center DIV between item and side?

Tags: html, css

I have a large div, that is centered where I want it on my computer. Any other computer it is not centered. I am talking about "midwrap" which is the big black box I having. I want it to be centered between the sidelinks and the side of wrapper which is the grey box it is in.

designatease.com

Thank-you in advance.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="midwrap"></div>
<a class="Resources">Resources</a>
<ul id="sidelinksleft">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="learn.html">Learn</a></li>
<li><a href="sites.html">Useful Sites</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
position:relative;
top:-82px;
margin-right:4%;
margin-left:4%;
width:92%;
height:100%;
background:#fafafa;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
overflow:hidden;
}

#sidelinksleft {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    position:relative;
    /*removed clear from here*/
    float:left;
    margin-left:-25px;
    top:16px;
}

#sidelinksleft li{
position:relative;
padding-top:3px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidelinksleft li a{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinksleft li a:hover{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#B0E2FF;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinksleft li a:active{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

.Resources{
color:#000000;;
font-size:16px;
font-family: sans-serif;
position:relative;
margin-left:-156px;
top:10px;
}

#midwrap {
    width:74%;
    height:95%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background:black;
    top:2%;
    position:relative;
    float:right; /*float right*/
    margin-right:5.5%;
}
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to keep your measurement units consistent.  Meaning that if you are using percentages for widths and heights, you use the same units for paddings, margins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should redo a simple template before to style it.

Using CSS rules for their behaviors might help:

1. `width` and `min-width` and `max-width`.
2. `float` and layout for adjacent elements
3. `text-align` and `display:inline-block` cause it sees floatting elements and `overflow:hidden;` is not usable there.

`margin` top should not be used in % cause it reflects % of  parent's width , not it's height **hey ! that's an unexpected behavior  isn't ?** *(so are % vertical padding if parents has a width in CSS)*

We can get to something like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AHhpG

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}
div, nav ,a {
  border:1px solid;
}
#main {
  width:90%;
  margin:1% auto 0;
  height:90%;
  min-width:800px;
}
nav {
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  max-width:20%;  
  width:200px;
}
nav a {
  display:block;
}
#box {
     display:inline-block;
  width:70%;
  height:90%;
  margin:1em 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: borders are to see where elements stands, whatch out , it can old margins of inside tags.